# GnuCASH - How to split a single bill in multiple due dates for payment?

Tags: accounting, gnucash, billing

It happens often that I have a single bill from a vendor and the payment is split along multiple dates, but I can't get how to do that and Gnucash docs don't explain it much.
So far, I split the bill itself adding a bill with the same number and the partial value, but I want to register it properly if there is a way.
In example:
1.200 USD total bill - to be paid in three 400 USD instalments

Now I am registering n.3 bills with the same bill number and date of 400 USD with different "due dates"

I want to be able to register n.1 bill of 1.200 USD and n.3 "due dates" of 400 USD.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You would like to register one bill with 3 different "due dates".  Other finance systems may be able to accommodate that (???) but I'm pretty sure that GnuCash cannot.  GnuCash is built by volunteers, and offered for free.  You can't really expect it to do all things desired by all men.

You've already implemented a workaround, that works - but with some disadvantages.  It requires extra work to set up 3 bills instead of one.  And the 3 bills all have the same bill number (which should be unique) but none of them match the original supplier bill.

But the reality of your situation is:

- You've received one bill from your supplier,
- Your supplier allows you to pay the bill in instalments over several dates,
- GnuCash is quite capable of recording partial payments against a bill, and
- It would be convenient to have some system provide a reminder to pay at the appropriate time.

I suggest that you:

1. record the bill in GnuCash (the whole amount as a single bill),
   specifying the payment "due date" as the final payment date allowed
   by your supplier.
2. Use an external calendar system to provide
   reminders to pay at the "multiple dates" when partial payment is
   allowed.  **"Pay $400 to MegaCorp today."**  You can use Microsoft
   Outlook, or Google Calendar, or your mother's wall calendar, or any
   convenient reminder system for this.
3. On the appropriate dates, record a partial payment in GnuCash against the bill from MegaCorp.

GnuCash will show the MegaCorp bill as "Unpaid" until the final payment is made.  It will, however, correctly show the reducing **amount outstanding** after each partial payment.

Comment: The _Scheduled Transactions_ mechanism seems to have the capacity to notify you of transactions ahead of time.

Comment: Kai, yes that's true.  You could record some Scheduled Transactions which should also provide reminders, but I don't think that any amounts paid by the Scheduled Transaction can automatically link to the specific invoice within the Accounts Payable system (although a transfer from "Bank Account" to "Accounts Payable" would reduce the running balance of Accounts Payable).  A further manual step would be required to Assign the Payment to the correct invoice.  Overall, this requires considerably more steps than simply recording a partial payment using the Pay Invoice function.